# Where I find a collection of document for information extraction?

Tags: document, gate, information-extraction

I am the beginner with the GATE framework, I'm finding a valid set of documents (pdf or other) where I can learn better this framework. On google I can not find anything appropriate, do you help me?

Comment: What about the **Gate Documentation** and **User Guide**?

Comment: on http://gate.co.uk there isn't a data source downloadable

Comment: Oh I see, you are looking for some data-set to play with...

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://gate-users-mailing-list-archive-read-only-no-new-topics-or-rep.1053641.n5.nabble.com/Gold-Standard-Annotations-Corpora-tp5709496.html

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/quick-start/ on the gate website.
They also have training modules with materials to get started.
I am also starting with Gate... Good luck =)